# Views over Append/Consume buffers in Direct3D 11

Tags: gpgpu, directx-11, hlsl

I'm using append/consume buffers to reduce shading work in my path-tracer (immediately shade empty space + emitters in a pre-pass, append the remaining pixels for full processing), and I've heard that I should be using a UAV when I'm accessing through `AppendStructuredBuffer<T>` and an SRV when I'm accessing through `ConsumeStructuredBuffer`. I haven't seen that claim in any of Microsoft's documentation, but it might explain why my calls to [Consume()] are returning empty data - is it accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have tested myself before I asked - shaders with `ConsumeStructuredBuffer`s declared in SRV registers (tN) fail to compile and emit an error saying they're only bindable through UAVs.

My `AppendStructuredBuffer` bound through the UAV registers works fine, so it seems like I was just quoting hearsay; unordered-access-views should be used for both HLSL types.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty cool project. Would love to see the results if you ever share anywhere!

Comment: It's almost ready! I'm on the very last stages of implementing BDPT with MIS + PSR, and I should have everything except for volumetrics (subsurface scattering and participating media) done tonight or tomorrow. I'll DM you when I'm finished :)

Comment: That would be awesome :)